# How can I make a menu-like form stay on the screen, on top of all other apps?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I want to make a menubar like window taskbar in C# but I'm wondering how can I make the form stay on the top of the screen and other program will not taped over it just like the window taskbar and when the mouse hover on a icon it will show a form like this:

[image: Example Image]

I have made it like this:
[image: Here]

And This is what I want[image: here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has a facility for this, allowing you to basically create pseudo-taskbars that dock to the side of the screen and are always visible. It was used by the Office team (possibly publically documented *for* the Office team?) a long, long time ago to create a desktop toolbar.

Anyway, they are called **Application Desktop Toolbars** (or "AppBars"), and the documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177.aspx). To register one, you call the `SHAppBarMessage` function with the [`ABM_NEW` message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787951.aspx). Complete sample code is available in the linked documentation, unfortunately it is in C++.

To use this from a C# application, you will have to P/Invoke. As far as I know, it is not wrapped by the .NET Framework anywhere, probably because it never gets used by anyone anymore. [This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6741/AppBar-using-C) appears to have the necessary P/Invoke definitions written out. I can't vouch for their correctness, but armed with the documentation and that as an example, you should be able to cook up a working demo.

There is another CodeProject article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part-3), written by Arik Poznanski as part of a series on using shell features from C#. It looks much more thorough, probably more than you need.

Answer (score -1):

Set the property `Form.TopMost` unless you have other programs creating topmost windows. Doh!

Comment: Thanks for the solution it worked but another problem occur that other program will be tapped over :)

Comment: Yes because you are debugging the application, I would set the property last once you have done your development. The application will run standalone anyway.